# QueryString.Add() gives "Specified method is not supported."

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to modify the query string in a request filter like so:

```cs
public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
{

    req.QueryString.Add("foo", "bar");
    
}
```

Bust ServiceStack throws error:

> Specified method is not supported

It seems that it is read only. How can I modify query string in a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the request which is immutable, you can add any per request items you want to attach to the request in `IRequest.Items` or you can update the `dto` Request DTO.

Comment: OK thanks.  I will add an item to check for later in the pipeline.